# No such module 'AWSCore' - Amazon FreeRTOS Bluetooth Low Energy Mobile SDK Demo Application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use an Amazon AWS iOS project. I think I am going through all the steps correctly. I have gone through the process no less than 5-10 times. Every time, I get the same error:

> No such module 'AWSCore'

The tutorial that I am trying to follow is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/ble-demo.html#ble-demo-wifi

I can see AWSCore in my **Pods** directory. I have tried several different suggestions here on StackOverflow, but nothing seems to make a difference.

Does anyone have some suggestions of what I might be doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the workspace file with extension ".xcworkspace" from Xcode?
Please make sure to open the workspace file (.xcworkspace) rather than project file (.xcodeProj). Entire workspace needs to be opened for Xcode to build the dependencies.

Comment: I have tried both. The tutorial actual tells you to open the .xcodeProj and it has these two configuration files in the Pods directory: Pods-AmazonFreeRTOSDemo.debug.xcconfig and Pods-AmazonFreeRTOSDemo.release.xcconfig. These files contain a list of framework search paths. This is not what I'm used to when working with pods. I typically open the .xcworkspace.  But when I open the workspace file, I get these two errors: 
:-1: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSServiceConfiguration
:-1: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSEndpoint

Comment: Did you perform a clean build of the workspace. There could be some cache from the project build so do a clean to make sure the cache is cleared and then perform build.

Comment: Yes, I have tried doing a clean build. I also went through the process of disintegrating the pods and reinstalling them, but no luck.

Comment: Disntegrating pods and reinstalling will still preserve the cache. So could you retry clean and build process at least 2 or 3 times. This is a once step process, and once the cache is cleaned then you can perform normal build process always.

Comment: These are the specific steps that I just went through: pod deintegrate, Clean Build Folder, sudo gem install cocoapods-clean, Clean Build Folder, pod clean, Clean Build Folder, (verify that "Pods" folder is gone), pod setup, Clean Build Folder, pod install, Clean Build Folder, Build. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.